# How to handle association table and cascade constraints in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I think this is a common problem but I was not able to find correct keywords to perform a search on StackOverflow.

In mysql, I have two entites : organization and scale.
One organization can only have one scale but a scale can belong to many organizations.

So I created a third entity organization_scale.

for instance :

```
organization
------------
org_id | name
     1 | Mickey
     2 | Donald
     3 | Dingo

scale
----------
 sc_id | name
     1 | miniScale
     2 | maxiScale 

organization_scale
--------------
org_id | sc_id
     1 | 1
     2 | 1
     3 | 2
```

Both fields of the organization_scale entity are foreign keys + cascade on update and delete

The problem is the following:

If I delete from organization where org_id = 3,the third line from organization_scale are properly deleted (since org_id = 3 does not exist anymore)

BUT

the scale with sc_id = 2 is not deleted. And I do not understand why. No one references to this scale, and this should be removed otherwise, with a big amount of data, a lot of "scales" will be orphean.

(same thing happens if I do not use an extra table, and I add a scale_id column directly in organization)

Comment: please, show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE scale` for each table. Do you have any triggers?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this: The `ON DELTE CASCADE` in the definition of the `organization_scale` table only works in one direction: when deleting something in `scale` or `organization` then don't ask and delete the rows in `organization_scale`.

But you seem to want the other direction: When deleting something in `organization_scale` delete the row in `scale` if there is no reference to it anymore.

This works for me: I added a trigger on `organization`.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;


CREATE TABLE organization (org_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE scale (sc_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE organization_scale (org_id INT UNSIGNED, sc_id INT UNSIGNED,
    FOREIGN KEY (org_id)
        REFERENCES organization(org_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (sc_id)
        REFERENCES scale(sc_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TRIGGER delete_unused_sc_id AFTER DELETE ON organization FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM scale WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM organization_scale WHERE organization_scale.sc_id = scale.sc_id);

INSERT INTO organization VALUES
(1,"Mickey"),
(2,"Donald"),
(3,"Dingo");

INSERT INTO scale VALUES
(1,"miniScale"),
(2,"maxiScale");

INSERT INTO organization_scale VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,2);

SELECT * FROM organization_scale;
SELECT * FROM scale;

DELETE FROM organization WHERE org_id=3;

SELECT * FROM organization_scale;
SELECT * FROM scale;


DROP DATABASE test;
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work since triggers are not "triggered" in cascade. If I have an other table with reference to an orgId, and I delete from this table, nothing will be triggered

Comment: Oh! Another table. That is important information. Please add it to your question. Of course my code only works for that smaller group of tables. If that is the only caveat, your could add another trigger on that table, tho.